# File comparison program for Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, hashing

I'm looking for a program I once heard of, but I can't remember its name. The program could generate hashes other programs and calculate the difference between two programs in percentages.

I vaguely remember the name having the word 'blue' or 'deep' and the letter 'f' in it.

Does anyone know the program I mean? I really could use it. It's open source btw.

Comment: What does that even mean? Calculate the differences in percentages?

Comment: If you want to see if two files are different just do an MD5 hash check. [FastSum MD5 Checker](http://www.fastsum.com/press/md5-hash.php)

Answer (score 0):

Beyondcompare?  No blue or deep or f for that matter but it does, if I recall, generate hashes of programs. http://www.scootersoftware.com/

Comment: No that's not it, it only hashes and compares 2 files, no folders or anything cross platform